# VBS - File Created But I Can't See It Or Open It

Tags: vbscript

I was trying to build a VBS to test creating files because a larger script I wrote isn't creating an output file. The point of the following script is to test functionality; which I'm not currently seeing.

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO, objFSOText, objFolder, objFile
Dim strDirectory, strFile
strDirectory = "C:\Test\next"
strFile = "\Try.txt"

' Create the File System Object
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Create the Folder specified by strDirectory on line 10
Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(strDirectory)

' -- The heart of the create file script
'-----------------------
'Creates the file using the value of strFile on Line 11
' -----------------------------------------------
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strDirectory & strFile)
Wscript.Echo "Just created " & strDirectory & strFile

Wscript.Quit
```

While running this code, everything works the first time but there isn't an output file in the destination directory. When I run it again it throws an error that the file already exists.

Comment: hi, the error comes from Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(strDirectory). each time u run the the code, u are creating the same directory C:\test\next... not the file

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can't see the directory as well. I tried showing hidden files in the parent folder but it didn't do anything.

Comment: dont u have a directory called next inside c:\test?

Comment: I've tried adding it, then I've taken it away. I feel as though my organization is quarantining the output somewhere.

Comment: Try Change the path to your desktop and check it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are trying to create the path `"C:\Test\next"`, which is a structure of two nested folders) in one go and also do not test if that path already exists.

To create a nested folder structure, I have added a small helper function `CreateNestedFolder` to your code and tidied it up a bit:

```
Option Explicit

Dim strDirectory, strFile, overwrite

strDirectory = "C:\Test\next"
strFile      = "Try.txt"
overwrite    = True  'set this to False if you do not wish to overwrite an existing file

'Create the (nested) Folder Structure specified by strDirectory if it does not exist yet
If Not CreateNestedFolder(strDirectory) Then
    Wscript.Echo "Could not create folder " & strDirectory
Else
    Dim objFSO, objFile
    ' Create the File System Object
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    ' -- The heart of the create file script
    '-----------------------
    'Creates the file using the value of strFile
    ' -----------------------------------------------

    'combine the directory and filename
    strFile = strDirectory & "\" & strFile
    'Create the new file and write something in it
    Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strFile, overwrite)
    objFile.WriteLine("This is a test.")
    objFile.Close
    Wscript.Echo "Just created " & strFile

    'Clean up the used objects
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objFSO  = Nothing
End If

Function CreateNestedFolder(ByVal sPath)
    'Helper function to create a nested folder structure.
    'Returns True on success, False otherwise
    Dim aFolders, oFso, i, firstIndex

    On Error Resume Next
    Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'Check if the path already exists
    If Not oFso.FolderExists(sPath) Then
        'Find the root drive and split the path in subfolder parts
        aFolders = Split(sPath, "\")
        'Get the root path from the complete path
        If Left(sPath, 2) = "\\" Then
            'If this is a UNC path then the root will be "\\server\share"
            sPath = "\\" & aFolders(2) & "\" & aFolders(3)
            firstIndex = 4
        Else
            'For a local path, the root is "X:"
            aFolders = Split(sPath, "\")
            sPath = aFolders(0)
            firstIndex = 1
        End If
        'Loop through the aFolders array and create new folders if needed
        For i = firstIndex to UBound(aFolders)
            If Len(aFolders(i)) > 0 Then
                sPath = sPath & "\" & aFolders(i)
                If Not oFso.FolderExists(sPath) Then oFso.CreateFolder sPath
            End If
        Next
    End If

    CreateNestedFolder = (Err.Number = 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set oFso = Nothing
End Function
```